# TXT file not showing properly in Android

Tags: android, text

I developed an app for Android, that loads some data from some .txt files I created. Until now, everything went fine. Today I updated these texts to add some stuff, and now Android comes out with this error in the LogCat:

```
06-06 23:16:03.925: W/System.err(7999): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "﻿72"
```

It never happened before. If I read the txt from my computer, I can see that all seems in the right place. But if I read it from the Android editor, I see strange symbols (close to that 72).

I don't know how to remove them, because I cannot see them on the pc!

Comment: What is 'the Android editor'?

Comment: Don't know. In my phone there are more than one app to open txt file: one is ES editor, that doesnt' show any extra character. The other one is simply called "editor".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file has special characters. To see them and remove them, use and editor like Notepad++  (It's free) and click on View -> Show Symbol -> show all characters

Notepad++ also has an Encoding menu, make sure that the detected encoding matches what you are using on Android

Comment: I knew Notepad++, but I didn't know the "show all characters" function.
It seemed to be something related to "\n" and other noew line things, now it works!

I really don't know why it happened though.. It's not the first time I edit those txts and it had always worked smoothly...